# Is there a way to use firebase authentication(mainly using mobile number) with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, firebase-authentication

If yes, can you point me to some resources on how to accomplish this task? Or share your expertise on this topic?

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for specific programming questions and answers. It's not a discussion forum, so your question is not a good fit for this site. Also, asking for tools, libraries, tutorials, or off-site resources recommendation is off-topic in here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Get your Firebase Api key

2 Check your JWT

```
 def firebase_verification(token)
      url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key=#{ENV['FIREBASE_API_KEY']}"
      firebase_verification_call = HTTParty.post(url, headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, body: { 'idToken' => token }.to_json )
      if firebase_verification_call.response.code == "200"
        firebase_infos = firebase_verification_call.parsed_response
      else
        raise CustomError
      end
    end
```

3 Create the user

```
def firebase_login(token)
  firebase_infos = firebase_verification(token)
  raise CustomError if uid != firebase_infos['users'][0]['localId'] 
  user = find_by(digits_id: firebase_infos['users'][0]['localId'])
  if user.nil?
    user = new
    user.email = ''
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token
    user.digits_id = firebase_infos['users'][0]['localId']
    user.digits_created_at = firebase_infos['users'][0]['createdAt']
  end
  user.phone_number = firebase_infos['users'][0]['phoneNumber']
  user.access_token = token
  user.save
  user
end
```

for more details check [this](https://medium.com/@Mpierrax/firebase-authentification-with-ruby-on-rails-backend-a9f7afc4d715) out

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can. Basically you are going to use **firebase auth** for authentication and your ruby app will get the authentication token and check if it is valid. I am not sure if there is an active ruby library to install for **firebase** (its always easier with a good lib) but you can use [Firebase rest api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) to check for the token.